# How can I disable mouse control of a Tkinter listbox?

Tags: python, tkinter

I was wondering whether it is possible to disable mouse control over a listbox in Tkinter. I want arrow keys navigation only. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a binding to an event, and in that binding you do `return "break"`, you will prevent the default behavior from being performed. Thus, you simply need to create your own bindings for events you don't want the user to be able to use.

For example:

```
...
    my_listbox.bind("<1>", self.no_op)
    my_listbox.bind("<Double-1>", self.no_op)
...
def no_op(self, event):
    return "break"
```

There may be a couple other bindings you need to disable, but that probably gets you 95% of the way there.

Comment: Another quick question: How would I set the focus on the listbox on load. Cause now I can't click on the listbox(I needed to do that before being able to use the arrow keys)

Comment: @user1804473: you can call the `focus_set` method. You also probably want to have the `<1>` binding set the focus as well, before returning `"break"`.